# IDLE unable to find PyQt5 installation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install and use PyQt5 on my Windows 10 computer. Actually, it's already installed but IDLE does not recognize the package.

I tried to import PyQt5 after I installed it but I got an import error.
Then I tried something else:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Here, I got a syntax error.
Does anybody have an idea what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `pip3` when you use python 3. Also: how did you import?

Comment: `from PyQt5 import *`

Comment: And `pip3 install pyqt5` is also a syntax error.

Comment: ...and what is the error?

Comment: You need to use `pip` in the console, not in the python interpreter

Comment: Ok, thank you, that helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Python 3.6.6 & PyQt5 on Windows (10)

Python3.6.6: Download & Install Python 3.6.6 https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

PyQt5: From an elevated command prompt run:

- python -m pip install --upgrade pip
- pip install pyqt5
- pip install pyqt5-tools
- Add the pyqt5 environment variable to the system environment path
  like so:

[image]

[Here](https://youtu.be/MnM5g0lm47g) is a youtube explaining the steps above